# Unity: Sprite renderer not working second time around

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, sprite, renderer

Ok, so continuing with my game, Im able to instantiate enemies and assign individual sprites to them on startup. When I destroy the enemies, and they all are destroyed when one is hit, I call that same function again. The inspector shows the gameobjects are there, but the sprite renderer component is blank. No error messages are displayed.
Here's my code simplified. This is where my instantiation and rendering method is at:

```
public class EnemySpawner : MonoBehaviour {

public Sprite[] HiraganaSprites;


public void setEnemies()
{
   int counter=0;
   while (counter<5)
   {

    Instantiate (EnemyPrefab, enemyPos, player.transform.rotation); 
        //label the enemy
        EnemyPrefab.tag = "Enemy" + counter;
        counter++;

   }

    //render diff sprites for each
    counter=0;
    while (counter<5)
    {
       string en_name="Enemy"+counter;
       labelEnemy = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag (en_name); 
       SpriteRenderer renderer=labelEnemy.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
       renderer.sprite=Sprites[counter];
       counter ++; 

    }
    void Awake()
   {
        Sprites = Resources.LoadAll<Sprite> ("kana");
    }
}
}
```

I make the call from a different script.

```
public EnemySpawner enemyspawner;
void function()
{
   enemyspawner=gameObject.AddComponent<EnemySpawner>();
   enemyspawner.setEnemies();
}
```

First time around, everything works fine! [image: See image]

Second time, nothing [image: nothing].

Weird thing is the prefabs are there, set on position, just not rendered. Also no error messages.
This is how Im destroying the enemies in case that helps.

```
while (i<=numenemies)
{
    string tag="Enemy"+i;
    destroyenemy=GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag(tag);
    Destroy(destroyenemy.gameObject);
    i++;
}
```

Comment: Why do you use `while (counter<5)` instead of a `for` loop?

Comment: And why do you loop twice over the same objects?

Comment: What for loop? And I loop twice over the same object cause im doing some other stuff around. I know its not ideal, but thats the way I have it set up right now. I dont think thats the problem though...

Comment: It doesn't look like there's something wrong with SpriteRenderer. I would say that something wrong with `HiraganaSprites`. What does it contain on your second take?

Answer (score 0):

You should attach `EnemySpawner` Script to gameObject and then update the script in which you call `setEnemies` function as follows -

```
public EnemySpawner enemyspawner;
void function()
{
   enemyspawner=gameObject.GetComponent<EnemySpawner>();
   enemyspawner.setEnemies();
}
```